# Get the local time of chosen timezone - Swift

Tags: swift, date, timezone, nsdate

I am creating a social media app. You can only post once every 24 hours, and I'm using it with firebase so all of the post' data goes to the firebase database.

When creating a post I have the variable `Date`, this is how you track if it's been 24 hours since the last post...

The only problem is that the user can just change the clock on their device and post as many times as they want. I need to get a date variable that is the local time of my timezone (EST) so I know that the data is accurate, but I'm not sure how to do it...

This is how I would usually get the current date:

```
let date = Date()
let currentTime = date.timeIntervalSince1970
```

So, I just need to get `currentTime` to be the current Eastern Standard Time (EST)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to allow the user to post once a day or if the user have posted 9pm then the user will only be able to post again after 9pm the day after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current timestamp form the firebase server and compare to the date from the last post

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

Go here for reference [firebase.database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue)

for firestore

```
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
```

Go here for reference [firebase.firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that 24 hours have passed, you need to compare the date in UTC, not in EST, UTC is a date without any time zone

and here

```
let date = Date()
let currentTime = date.timeIntervalSince1970
```

you have UTC timestamp

UPD: the fact of publication itself should be checked exclusively on the server, while the server should take its UTC time and check the time of the last publication from the database, before publishing.

Comment: This won't solve the problem when the user changes the device time manually.

Comment: @LeoDabus 
the fact of publication itself should be checked exclusively on the server, while the server should take its UTC time and check the time of the last publication from the database, before publishing, perhaps the author wanted to do only a visual check of the publication possibility ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not trusting the device time, you could probably use an NTP client to get the date through an internet connection.

There are some implementations written in Swift like [TrueTime](https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift) and [Kronos](https://github.com/lyft/Kronos).
Both appears to use by default `time.apple.com`.

Their respective guides (on README files) seems to be pretty straightforward.

Example using `TrueTime`:

```
let client = TrueTimeClient()
client.start()
client.fetchIfNeeded { result in
    switch result {
    case let .success(referenceTime):
        // Current date
        let now = referenceTime.now()
        client.pause()
    case let .failure(error):
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Example using `Kronos`:

```
Clock.sync { date, offset in
    // Current date
    print(date)
}
```